# Jquery: Hide and show a div when image is hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I wonder if someone can help me find a solution to an effect hover to an image in my blog.
The idea was when I hover an image, you see a div with the image information, link project name, date,...

What i have done is, assign two classes do the div information, class `show` and class `hide`, and at the beginning it apears with a class `hide`.

Then with jQuery/JavaScript when the `img:hover` it remove the class `hide` and add a class `show`.

the problem is, when i do hover to a image, appears the information of all images.

I am wonder if some can help me to make just appear the information of the image that the mouse are hover.

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1" height="290" width="220" />
  <div class="information hide">
      <h2>Titulo</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Projecto 1" height="290" width="220" />
  <div class="information hide">
      <h2>Titulo</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
body div.information {
background: rgba(219, 49, 49, 0.52);
width: 220px;
height: 290px;
position: relative;
top: -290px;
}
```

/*  HOVER EFFECT */

```
.hide {
display: none;
}

.show {
display: block;
}
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
$('img').hover(function() {
    $('.information').addClass("mostrar");
    $('.information').removeClass("hide");      
});
```

And by the way, if some one can tell me, how to hide the information again when the image is not hover, I appreciate to.

Answer (score 3):

What about something simpler:

```
$("div.content > img").hover(function() {
    $(this).next(".information").show(); //hover in
}, function() {
    $(this).next(".information").hide(); //hover out
});
```

This way, using jquery **.show** and **.hide** you don't need to use the css which you created for the hover effect, since these jquery's functions already take care of the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to support IE7 and lower, you can do this with just CSS using the [*adjacent sibling combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) selector, no JavaScript required:

```
img + div.information {
    display: none;
}
img:hover + div.information {
    display: block;
}
```

That says: "Hide `div.information` when it's immediately after an `img`" but "Show `div.information` when it's immediately after a *hovered* `img`". The latter rule being both later in the CSS and (I *think*) more specific, it wins when the image is hovered and not when it isn't.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/esehod) - Works in modern browsers, including IE8 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is, when i do hover to a image, appears the information of all images.

I believe this is because you're referencing the generic information class, not the id of a single div. Instead, use the adjacent sibling reference to get only the information for the image you're hovering. You could use the :nth-child() selector.

```
$("#content:nth-child(1)")
```

Also, you shouldn't have multiple divs with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().find('.information').addClass("mostrar")
    .removeClass("hide");
```

This will grab the parent of the individual img which is being hovered, search within the parent and find the `.information` specific to that img.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('img').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.information').removeClass('hide').addClass('mostrar').addClass('show');

}, function(){
    $(this).siblings('.information').removeClass('show').removeClass('mostrar').addClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('img').hover(function() {
    $('.information').addClass("hide")
    $(this).next().addClass("mostrar").removeClass("hide");
}, function(){
    $('.information').addClass("hide").removeClass("mostrar")
});
```